# Is it possible to configure HTTPS for .net core API in IIS only ( whitout "heavy" .net core modification)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, https, asp.net-core-webapi

I did a very little .net core web API , my goal is to receive a XML from a POST and to write this XML on my HDD.

I would like to use HTTPS.

When i created my project in VS, i checked the HTTPS support and if i run the application in debug mode, https is enabled and OK ( with IIS Express).

Since my API is OK, i published it on IIS ( Not IIS express).
It works in HTTP.

I modify IIS in order to enable HTTPS support and modify my appsettings.json in order to add the
**"https_port": 444**

I rebooted the IIS server and if i try to run https://localhost:444 i got :

```
HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.
```

I searched about how to enable https on IIS for asp.net core and i only got some tutorials with heavy code modifications. I'm looking for the "simplest" way to enable https and i wonder if i could enable https only through modify IIS configuration.

Is it possible ?

I use .net core app 3.1

Thanks a lot guys :)

Comment: You need to configure this within the IIS site bindings for your site as that is what requests hit first before any .net stuff.  Assuming you have a SSL certificate installed in the certificate store see this: https://www.digicert.com/kb/util/ssl-certificate-configuration-iis-8.htm

Comment: Thanks, i had a mistake on my code. Now, i juste have : "Connection to https://localhost refused". I did the binding with https and the certificate.

Comment: I looking your website and it's exactly what i did

Comment: Your testing this on the same machine as IIS is running?

Comment: YEs ! Correction....i had another mistake..Now, i get a HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.

Comment: Have you checked your Event Viewer for additional details on the 503 error in iis?

Comment: Yes, i have nohting in application and system :(

Comment: As far as I know, the 503 error means the IIS application pool may be down, I suggest you could open IIS manager console and click that application pool to check this application pool is working well or not.